# Помогите исправить обработку матрицы

Tags: javascript

Цель в том, чтобы найти в матрице нули и заполнить нулями принадлежащие к элементу строку и столбец.

Написал функцию, которая по идее должна работать, но как я понял, на этапе перезаписи происходят что то непонятное для меня и все элементы обнуляются, подскажите как это исправить.

```
const myMatrix = [
[0, 2, 3, 4, 5],
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
[1, 2, 0, 4, 5],
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
[0, 2, 3, 4, 5]
];

function func (matrix) {
    const matrixTemp = matrix.slice()

  matrix.forEach ((row, rowIndex) => {

    row.forEach((rowElem, elemId) => {
    
    if(rowElem === 0) {
        matrix[rowIndex].forEach((item,index) => {
        if(matrixTemp[rowIndex][index] === 0) {
            return
        }
            matrixTemp[rowIndex][index] = 0
        })
        
        matrix.forEach((item, index) => {
            if(matrixTemp[index][elemId] === 0) {
            return
          }
            matrixTemp[index][elemId] = 0
        })
    }

    })
  })
  
  return matrixTemp
}

console.log("result:", func(myMatrix))
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
const resultMatrix = [
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 2, 0, 4, 5],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 2, 0, 4, 5],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здраствуйте , проблема вашего кода это вот эта строчка:

```
const matrixTemp = matrix.slice()
```

Массивы имеют ссылочный тип данных , и для того чтобы один не ссылался на другой вы решили ,что пустого slice будет достаточно. Но нет, это прекрасно работает с одномерными массивами ,а вот с многомерными уже не работает.

Можете заменить вашу проблемную строчку на вот эту:

```
const matrixTemp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(matrix));
```

Это строчка конвертирует матрицу в строчный вид , и обратно достаёт из строчного.

Comment: Отлично, благодарю, пол дня просидел с этим затупом.

Answer (score 1):

```
const cols = [],
      rows = [];

//Получаем колонки и ряды которые заполним нулями
myMatrix.forEach((row, rowId) => {
  row.forEach((n, colId) => {
    if(n === 0){        
      cols.push(colId);
      rows.push(rowId);
    }
  })
});

//Заполняем нулями
const result = myMatrix.reduce((res, row, rowId) => {
  if(rows.includes(rowId)){
    return [...res, Array.from({length: row.length}).fill(0)];
  } 
  return [...res, row.map((col, colId) => cols.includes(colId) ? 0 : col)];
}, []);
```

Comment: Спасибо конечно, ваше решение покрасивей, но хотелось бы все таки понять, в чем проблема именно в моем способе.

Comment: @MrYogurt Потому что вы проходитесь по массиву и одновременно меняете его значения. И если к примеру вы находитесь на 1 элементе и этот элемент 0, то вы меняете весь массив на 0, это означает что 2 элемент мог быть любое число отличительное от 0(3 к примеру) но из-за того что вы поменяли значение всего массива на предыдущей итерации то это число теперь не 3 а 0, и весь столбец меняется на 0, соответственно весь массив превращается в 0. Нужно сначало пройтись по всему массиву, найти индексы колонок и рядов, которые нужно изменить, и уже после того как вы все получили - менять.

Comment: Да, я сразу же подумал об этом и запускал циклы относительно myMatrix. Т.е я при оценке матрицы опирался на исходник, а записывал все в matrixTemp. И это тоже не помогло. Но даже в примере выше, по идее не должно быть перезаписи входящей матрицы matrix, ибо я копирую значение в другую переменную и уже работаю с ней, не меняя то, с чем работают циклы.

Comment: @MrYogurt Не сразу заметил что копируете массив.
Нашел проблему: в 1 строке функции когда копируете массив, то создается новый массив а элементами служат ссылки на внутренние массивы, т.е копируется только внешний массив а ссылки внутри ссылаются на элементы из matrix. Код верный просто измените 1 строку на 
const matrixTemp = matrix.slice().map(item => item.slice());

Comment: Благодарю, но человек выше уже объяснил в чем причина. Затупил на ровном месте.